# C++ template template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

As a contrived example, let's say I want to write a type that can add a new template template parameter to a type that has a variadic template template parameter pack:

```
namespace
{
template <template <typename...> typename... T>
struct foo {};

template <typename Original, template <typename...> typename T>
class add_to_foo {
    template <template <typename...> typename... V>
    struct appender {
        using type = foo<V..., T>;

        explicit appender(foo<V...>) {}
    };

    template <template <typename...> typename... V>
    appender(foo<V...>) -> appender<V...>;

public:
    using type = typename decltype(appender(std::declval<Original>()))::type;
};
}

int main() {
    using original_foo = foo<std::vector, std::basic_string>;
    using new_foo = typename add_to_foo<original_foo, std::deque>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<new_foo, foo<std::vector, std::basic_string, std::deque>>);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[It works](https://godbolt.org/z/x5rjcznYM), but it's limited in that `appender` only works with `foo` rather than a generic template parameter.  Let's try to replace `foo` with a [template template parameter](https://godbolt.org/z/4KK8jeEvb):

```
namespace
{
template <template <typename...> typename... T>
struct foo {};

template <typename Original, template <typename...> typename T>
class add_to_u {
    template <template <typename...> typename U, template <typename...> typename... V>
    struct appender {
        using type = U<V..., T>;

        explicit appender(U<V...>) {}
    };

    template <template <typename...> typename U, template <typename...> typename... V>
    appender(U<V...>) -> appender<V...>;

public:
    using type = typename decltype(appender(std::declval<Original>()))::type;
};
}

int main() {
    using original_foo = foo<std::vector, std::basic_string>;
    using new_foo = typename add_to_u<original_foo, std::deque>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<new_foo, foo<std::vector, std::basic_string, std::deque>>);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This doesn't work, there are lot's of errors, but the main ones are:

```
<source>:14:25: error: use of template template parameter 'V' requires template arguments
        using type = U<V..., T>;
<source>:23:36: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'appender'
    using type = typename decltype(appender(std::declval<Original>()))::type;
```

It *looks* like the compiler thinks that the template arguments of `U` need to be complete types rather than template template parameters, this isn't the case when `foo` was used *presumably* because the compiler could see that it used template template parameters.  So I need to tell the compiler that `U` is a template template parameter whose parameters are also template template parameters - any idea how?

Comment: The problem is that `V` is a template template parameter. This means 2 things: **1)** `V` can match class templates or alias template **2)** When using `V` we usually have to supply template arguments inside angle brackets `<>`. In your example, `V...` won't work because you haven't supplied any arguments.

Comment: `template <typename...> typename U` is a class template taking regular type parameters. `template <template <typename...> typename...> typename U` is the class template taking template template parameters. Once this and a few more obvious syntax problems are fixed, [the code compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/fzz7jWefb)

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, I didn't realise I could 'nest' the template template parameter syntax like that.  Make your comment an answer and I'll accept.